# Why do we need a Homomorphic Filter?

Tags: filters, frequency-domain, frequency-filters

Please, explain in layman's terms,

1. Why do we need a Homomorphic Filter?
2. In what kind of situations should we use Homomorphic filtering?
3. What kind of images need Homomorphic filtering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, tell what is not enough "layman".

1. Because standard linear smoothing (like averaging) tends to filter noise but reduces the contrast. Image composition is not often linear: cast shadows, occlusions. So linear methods tend to be suboptimal.
2. When you want to preserve sharp contrasts, for instance with multiplicative noise (whose intensity varies with image intensity), when you have a slow variation of the global illumination across the image (like progressive shadowing effect), when you want to both denoise and enhance
3. Images taken under varying illumination conditions, with noise varying with intensities, for instance related to temperature (infrared, visible of hot objects).

Answer (score 0):

Realtime Homomorphic filter :
https://youtube.com/shorts/bL9Zu6_mdOI?feature=share

The homomorphic filter is a generalized technique in image processing for dealing with lighting variations in images. It was originally introduced in signal processing to convert convolution into multiplication. It is based on the homomorphism property of logarithms, where log(a*b) = log(a) + log(b), allowing a multiplicative process to be changed into an additive one.

This is especially useful in image processing where the illumination-reflectance model of an image is a multiplicative one. The image brightness is seen as a product of the illumination and the reflectance components. Illumination represents the lighting condition, while reflectance is the property of the object in the image itself.

The Homomorphic filter can separate the illumination and the reflectance components, which makes it possible to handle each component separately. This filter is often used to correct non-uniform illumination in images and to enhance contrast.

Here's a very basic version of the steps used to apply a Homomorphic filter:

1. Take the logarithm of the image, changing the multiplicative model into an additive one.
2. Apply a high-pass filter to this log image. This allows you to deal separately with the high-frequency (reflectance) and the low-frequency (illumination) parts of the image.
3. Take the exponent of the result to obtain the final image.

Please note, an actual implementation might involve more complex steps, such as using a more complex filter than a simple high-pass filter.